# How to properly declare and call a 3 dimensional map in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, 3d

I'm programming a minecraft type of game isometrically.

Basically I have my X, Y, Z and the block type.

How do I declare this the best way so when I input the XYZ coordinates, the block type is returned?

E.G

```
function block(x, y, z, type) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.type = type;
}

var map = new Array();
map[0] = new Array();
map[0][0] = new Array();

map[0][0][0] = new Block(0,0,0,grass);
map[0][0][1] = new Block(0,0,1,stone);
....
//hundreds of times later

ctx.drawImage(map[myPositionX][myPositionY][myPositionZ].type);
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around this on how to do this without it getting messy.

Can I do this with just objects? Do I have to have a 3D array? I don't get it

**UPDATE**

Is this really the right way to do this?

```
//Map
function Block(x, y, z, type) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.type = type;
}

var map = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){       
    map[i] = [];        
    for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        map[i][j] = [];

        for(var k = 0; k < 10; k++){
            map[i][j][k] = new Block(i,j,k,"neutral");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code provided you are using an Array. This is one way to do it. if you feel confortable with it, go with this

Comment: One of the reasons I don't like doing arrays is how I must start off with 0,0,0 and cant just jump into, lets say, 142,156,123; only when I define everything. And defining something like that would take a very long time in a loop. Isn't there any other better way?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7701035/4245446). I created a snippet to show you how to integrate it inside your code.

You can now access your position with `map[142][156][123]`

```js
function setPropertySafe(obj) {
  function isObject(o) {
    if (o === null) return false;
    var type = typeof o;
    return type === 'object' || type === 'function';
  }
  if (!isObject(obj)) return;
  var prop;
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
    prop = arguments[i];
    if (!isObject(obj[prop])) obj[prop] = {};
    if (i < arguments.length - 2) obj = obj[prop];
  }

  obj[prop] = arguments[i];
}

function block(x, y, z, type) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
  this.type = type;
}

var map = {};
setPropertySafe(map, 142, 156, 123, new block(142, 156, 123, 'grass'));

console.log(map);
console.log(map[142][156][123].type);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I needed. Although if you could clarify the code a bit how it works I would very much appreciate it

Comment: @tery.blargh You can follow the link to the question

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays arrays in Javascript are sparse arrays.
You can define two helper methods to get and set a block.
There is no reason to keep the block coordinates in the block itself and thus, the only attribute of a block remains it's type:

```
map = []; //array

getBlock = function(x,y,z) {
   if (map[x] == null)
      return null;
   if (map[x][y] == null)
      return null;

   return map[x][y][z];
}

setBlock = function(x,y,z,type) {
   if (map[x] == null)
      map[x] = [];
   if (map[x][y] == null)
      map[x][y] = [];

    map[x][y][z] = type;
}
```

This will get you started.
Eventually you will realize that storing a single block as a `Number` will take too much memory. You will have to split your map into `sectors` where each sector will encode multiple blocks as a `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, having a three dimensional array of position is not an efficient way of going about it, as this grows as O(xyz).

Is there a specific reason why you would need your whole space to be covered ? Is there a block for each possible xyz combination ?

A better way would be to store blocks in a hash table (object) or in an array.

```
function getCubeIdFromLocation({ x, y, z }, { min, cubeSize }) {
  const cubeX = Math.floor((x - min[0]) / cubeSize[0])
  const cubeY = Math.floor((y - min[1]) / cubeSize[1])
  const cubeZ = Math.floor((z - min[2]) / cubeSize[2])

  return (`cube${cubeX}${cubeY}${cubeZ}`)
}

function getHashTableAndLookupCubes(...blocks) {
  const hashBlocks = {}
  const lookupCubes = {}
  let min = [0, 0, 0]
  let max = [0, 0, 0]
  for (let i = 0; i < blocks.lenght; i++) {
    const block = blocks[i]
    hashBlocks[`block${i}`] = block

    min = [
      block.x < min[0] ? block.x : min[0],
      block.y < min[1] ? block.y : min[1],
      block.z < min[2] ? block.z : min[2],
    ]

    max = [
      block.x > max[0] ? block.x : max[0],
      block.y > max[1] ? block.y : max[1],
      block.z > max[2] ? block.z : max[2],
    ]
  }
  // lets say you divide the space in 10 for each dimension
  const gridSize = [10, 10, 10]
  const cubeSize = [
    (max[0] - min[0]) / gridSize[0],
    (max[1] - min[1]) / gridSize[1],
    (max[2] - min[2]) / gridSize[2],
  ]

  const gridParameters = { min, max, gridSize, cubeSize }

  for (let i = 0; i < hashBlocks.length; i++) {
    const block = hashBlocks[i]

    const cubeX = Math.floor((block.x - min[0]) / cubeSize[0])
    const cubeY = Math.floor((block.y - min[1]) / cubeSize[1])
    const cubeZ = Math.floor((block.z - min[2]) / cubeSize[2])
    const cubeId = `cube${cubeX}${cubeY}${cubeZ}`

    // You could also use
    // const cubeId = getCubeIdFromLocation({ x: block.x, y: block.y, z: block.z }, gridParameters)

    if (lookupCubes.hasOwnProperty(cubeId)) {
      lookupCubes[cubeId].children.push(block)
    } else {
      lookupCubes[cubeId] = { x: cubeX, y: cubeY, z: cubeZ, children: [] }
    }
  }

  return ({ hashBlocks, lookupCubes, gridParameters })
}

getHashTableAndLookupCubes(blockList)
```

If you have a lot of blocks, to limit the amount of search necessary you could cache position of blocks in "smaller cubes" that have an x,y,z position and are width*height*depth, and lookup only blocks inside the corresponding cubes when looking for a block at a certain position.

You could also cache the neighbours of your block inside a neighbour variable and tree search. (not shown in the code)

Another possibility would be to use [a Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)